# What is the best way to check if an address already exists

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to avoid having duplicates of the same address in my database. What's the best (and/or fastest) way to check if it already exists?

My initial approach is to have something like this

```sql
CREATE TABLE addresses ( 
  id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  line_1 VARCHAR(40),
  line_2 VARCHAR(40),
  line_3 VARCHAR(40),
  postal_code VARCHAR(40),
  hash_code VARCHAR(32) AS (MD5(CONCAT(line_1, line_2, line_3, postal_code)))
);
```

This will create an `MD5` has of the fields and then I can just check if I have an address with that hash already.

I understand that this is case sensitive but that doesn't matter. What I want is a fast and easy way to check if I have and address with the same exact data without having to compare every column separately.

Here is a fiddle with the above example : https://dbfiddle.uk/DDPmd7d_

Comment: Unique indices are a thing, look them up before trying to building one yourself.

Comment: Fiddle is "not found"

Comment: You may already be doing this but you would need to standardise your address fields for any solution to work. Not just case but abbreviations (Road v. Rd, East Sussex v. E. Sussex, etc) and any other potential differences in how addresses can be provided

Comment: Addresses are notoriously difficult to do this with because of possible variations of the same address, e.g. If I live in flat 1a, 24 some road, this might be entered all in line 1 as "Flat 1a, 24 Some Road", or just "1a, 24 Some Road" or "1a 24 Some Road" or "1.a. 24 Some Road", then add in that some people might shorten "Road" to "Rd" then add in that some people might do this over two lines as "Flat 1a", then "24 Some Road". Before you know it you can have many variations of the same address. This is pretty much why you'll find most sites now use an address lookup.

Comment: I assume the same for all countries, but haven't had to deal with international addresses yet, but in the UK there is a UPRN (Unique Property Reference Number) from a standard list of all UK addresses - this would be your unique key here, for the reasons mentioned using free type and keeping addresses unique are pretty much mutually exclusive unless you have very very clever fuzzy matching in place

Comment: Why are you messing around with hash codes? Just use do a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` and make sure you have a multi-column index on `line_1, line_2, line_3, postal_code`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hash on raw concatenated strings has the problem that it cannot tell out `'s' + 'carpet'` from `'scar' + 'pet'`. It also won't prevent duplicates if any application or person with DB access inserts data.

Your columns are short, nothing prevents you from using a regular unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_address ON addresses (line_1, line_2, line_3, postal_code);
```

You can check if an address exists with a simple SELECT query:

```
select *
from addresses
where line_1 = 'foo 1'
and line_2 = 'foo 2'
and line_3 = 'foo 3'
and postal_code = 'pc1';
```

If you try to bypass checks, MySQL will reject the insert:

> Duplicate entry 'Foo 1-Foo 2-FOO 3-PC1' for key 'addresses.unique_address'

Or you can just skip the check altogether and catch the exception in your application code.

It also has the added benefit that you can set collation to your liking, so you can consider `'FOO'` and `'foo'` the same, or different, as you need.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/X6mIaD7x)

Of course, all this approach can prevent is stuff like processing one record twice by mistake. Fed with human supplied info, it won't accomplish too much.

Comment: Thank you. What about performance? Would having a unique index be faster than comparing the generated hash value?

Most of the data will come from an API, so my only concern is really if the `line_1` I have in my database already exists. It's their problem to make sure the data they send me is sanitized.

Either way, I'll accept your solution since it looks like the most sane approach. I'll see if I can run some benchmarks myself in the future.

Comment: We can get philosophical here. If not enforced by DB, it can be bypassed. If it's wrong, does it matter it's fast? In any case, you still need to search for the hash. I don't expect it to perform significantly different from searching for the index. But, as you suggested, nothing beats a good benchmark under your real conditions.